# no method named `connect_activate` when using the gtk crate

Tags: gtk, rust

I am trying to write simple GTK application in Rust, but faced with problem that I cannot add signal to menu item. There is simplified code to reproduce problem:

Glade file ("interface.glade"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="menubar1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">File</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu1">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="FileMenu">
                        <property name="label">gtk-new</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Rust code ("main.rs"):

```
extern crate gtk;

mod example {
    use gtk;
    use gtk::traits::*;
    use gtk::signal::Inhibit;
    use gtk::widgets::{
        Builder,
        MenuItem
    };
    use gtk::Window;

    pub fn main() {
        gtk::init().unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Failed to initialize GTK."));
        let builder = Builder::new_from_file("./interface.glade").unwrap();
        let window: Window = builder.get_object("window1").unwrap();

        window.connect_delete_event(|_, _| {
            gtk::main_quit();
            Inhibit(true)
        });

        let file_menu: MenuItem = builder.get_object("FileMenu").unwrap();
        file_menu.connect_activate(|_| {
            println!("Activated");
        });

        window.show_all();
        gtk::main();
    }
}

fn main() {
    example::main()
}
```

And when I try to compile it, I get an error:

```
src/main.rs:24:19: 26:11 error: no method named `connect_activate` found for type `gtk::widgets::menu_item::MenuItem` in the current scope
src/main.rs:24         file_menu.connect_activate(|_| {
src/main.rs:25             println!("Activated");
src/main.rs:26         });
src/main.rs:24:19: 26:11 note: the method `connect_activate` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `gtk::widgets::menu_item::MenuItem : gtk::traits::button::ButtonTrait`
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please include what version of the crates you are using. If I try to compile your example with `gtk 0.0.2`, I get 3 unrelated errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Yep! You aren't reading and addressing the error message:

> the method `connect_activate` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `gtk::widgets::menu_item::MenuItem : gtk::traits::button::ButtonTrait`

Granted, this error message is worded in an obtuse manner. It's saying that the type `MenuItem` does not implement the trait `ButtonTrait`. To be honest, this is the first time I've see this particular wording of the error message, so I might be a bit wrong. If you check out the documentation(1) for `MenuItem` though, you can see that it does not implement `ButtonTrait`. This precludes you from calling the method.

I don't know what a suitable workaround is. I don't see any [examples that use `MenuItem`](https://github.com/rust-gnome/examples). The 3 linked example projects don't use it either. It's entirely possible that it simply hasn't had all of the appropriate traits implemented yet. Perhaps this would be a good chance for you to get some commits into an up-and-coming project! ^_^

I also couldn't find any fallback methods or traits that would allow you to call `connect` directly.

(1): I wish I could link to the docs, but there are no officially-hosted versions I can find.

Comment: Honestly, I've read the error message but thought that I forgot to include some traits etc. It often happens when I use rust. But now I understood that it is a bug and as you say I can try to fix library code. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @Lodin: I am in your boat, the error messages related to absent methods are not crystal clear; many times the compiler has recommended me to "use the trait" when it was already used and the issue was not satisfying the bounds...